# Solving $\int \frac{3}{2} x e^{-6 x} d x$ using $u$-substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

> $$\int \frac{3}{2} x e^{-6 x} d x$$

Hi, I was solving an equation and I came to a part requiring that I solve $\int{\frac{3}{2}xe^{-6x}dx}$.
I attempted to solve this using $u$-sub but got the wrong answer, I set $u = e^{-6x}$.

$$
\quad \begin{aligned}
\text { Let } u & =e^{-6 x} d u \\
d u & =-6 e^{-6 x} d x \\
\frac{d u}{6} & =e^{-6 x} d x
\end{aligned} \\
\int \frac{3}{2} x e^{-6 x} dx\to\frac{3}{2} \int x \frac{d u}{6} \\ \to\frac{3}{12} \int{x}=\frac{3}{12} \cdot \frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{3 x^2}{24}=\frac{1}{8} x^2 \\
$$

I was wondering why this strategy didn't work. Is it because after the $u$-sub the integral is with respect to $u$ and I was left with an $x$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: **Hint**: Use integration by parts.

Comment: I have edited the question  this time since you will require some time to familiarise with the mathjax commands. However, for future questions please follow the rules of this website (and mathjax) in the above comment.

Comment: Now on the question, how did you go from $\int{x  \cdot \dfrac{du}{6}}$ to $\int{x}$?

Comment: After changing $xe^{-6x}dx$ to $(x/6)du$, the integral is now on $u$ and so you also need to express the integrand $x/6$ in terms of $u$, which gives $-\ln(u)/36$, so now the integral is $-(3/2)\int\ln(u)du/36$

Comment: I agree with @Dstarred ... you get integral $\int x \, du$, but then you compute instead the integral $\int x \,dx$, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @GEdgar yes, I think thats where i was making my mistake. So to solve this integral i would have to integrate x in terms of u, right? I know this can be solved using integration by parts, but i was just curious as to if it can be solved using u-sub aswell.

Comment: @MengchunZhang thank you, I solved the integral like this and was able to get the correct answer

Comment: @Mattel Nice to know it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: If the integrand is a logarithm, inverse trigonometric function, inverse hyperbolic function, or a product of $x^m$ with $\ln x$, $e^{ax}$, $\sin{ax}$ or $\cos{ax}$ or their inverses, then the solution can be got by a single or repeated **integration by parts**.

Hence, in your problem we can choose: $u=x \implies du=dx,\, $ and $\, dv=e^{-6x}dx \implies v=-\frac{1}{6}e^{-6x}$.

Therefore we have:
$$\int \frac{3}{2}xe^{-6x}\mathrm dx=\frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{6}xe^{-6x}+\frac{1}{6}\int e^{-6x}\mathrm dx \right)=-\frac{1}{4}xe^{-6x}-\frac{1}{24}e^{-6x}=\boxed{-\frac{1}{4}e^{-6x}\left(x+\frac{1}{6} \right)}.$$